# node to traverse cannot be null set foreign key constraint

Tags: java, jpa

I want to turn on and off the foreign key constraint and I did this:

```
em.createQuery("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0").getResultList().
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
```

Comment: Never turn off foreign key checks. What you want to do exactly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48182028/cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-after-disable-foreign-key-checks

Comment: I want to update a key that is FK in other table.

Comment: Ok I know it but what will happen to records in other table. There is a reason for foreign key checks default value is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createQuery` won't recognise native queries. You have to use `createNativeQuery` method.

Assuming you know the impact of `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`. Disabling that may lead you into other serious issues of data loss.