# Cannot delete or update a parent row after disable foreign key checks

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I want to update the key in a table and this key is FK in other tables.

```
em.createNativeQuery("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0").getResultList().

em.createNativeQuery("update user set name = ?1  where name = ?2").executeUpdate();

query.setParameter(1, "aa");
query.setParameter(2, "bb");
```

However i get an exception even if I disabled the foreign key checks.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`test_import_1`.`assessment_user`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK32kg3rlqty5i2i729a22icn7q` FOREIGN KEY (`user_name`) REFERENCES
>   `user` (`name`))

Answer (score 1):

What about using both queries as one query like :

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("BEGIN ")
    .append("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0 ;")//query to disable foreign key checks
    .append("UPDATE user SET name = ?1 WHERE name = ?2;")//The update query
    .append("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1")//when you finish enable the check 
    .append(" END;");

Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query.toString());
query.setParameter(1, "aa");
query.setParameter(2, "bb");
q.executeUpdate();// Note executeUpdate() should be used AFTER you set the parameters
```

**Second option :**

```
em.createNativeQuery("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0").executeUpdate();

Query q = em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE user SET name = ?1 WHERE name = ?2;");
query.setParameter(1, "aa");
query.setParameter(2, "bb");
q.executeUpdate();

em.createNativeQuery("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1").executeUpdate();
```